# powershell: cpu usage, function does not work for value 100

Tags: powershell

I am trying to provide a short script to inform me about the CPU usage over some limet but it works only if CPU < 100% but fails if it works 100% CPU

```
$trashhold=90 
$doit=Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average | Out-String

if ($doit -match "\d+"){ 
$doit = $matches[0]; 
}

if ($doit -gt $trashhold)
    {
        send email bla bla
    }
else 
    {
        Write-Output "less than $limit, do nothing"
    }
```

Basically regex takes number values from Get-WmiObject function and script works if cpu is 99 or less. For 100 it goes for else even it is bigger than trashhold (90). Where is the mistake?

try to catch error but withoout results (regex is returning correct numbers)

Comment: In addition to Santiagos answer, you're comparing a number to a string. Your immediate fix would be to swap operands, but as mentioned, there's no need to pipe to `Out-String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `Out-String` and no need for [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) either, you're just overcomplicating it:

```
$threshold = 90
$cpuUsage  = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average).Average 

if($cpuUsage -gt $threshold) {
    # send email blah blah with `$cpuUsage`
}
else {
    "Less than $threshold, do nothing"
}
```

What you're looking to do is to obtain the [**Property Value**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.3#property-values) from the `LoadPercentage` Property, this can be done either via [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) (as shown in this answer) or using [`Select-Object -ExpandProperty LoadPercentage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-9-show-the-intricacies-of-the-expandproperty-parameter). [`ForEach-Object LoadPercentage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-6-get-property-values) would also work (see [`-MemberName` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#-membername) for more info). There are other methods too, though these are the most common ones.

Comment: Yes, it helps for CPU 100%. However, how to get a value of CPU usage into email when there is no variable keeping the value? I am using $msg.Body = "Alert, CPU is ..."

Comment: @donut_duncker I edited my question, hope that makes more sense now